# Syncing documentDB(Azure CosmosDB) data to On-Premises database

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We already written a job which syncs the data from DocumentDB to OnPrem DB. This job we add into the task scheduler where we set an interval for 5 minutes. After syncing is done we are deleting this job from documentDB. This job is working fine.

However our problem is if error occurs we are only logging the error details but we need to send email to the user for the error details.

So that we have decided to write new email job which will send the mail to the user based on the data is stuck or any other issue for more than 5 minutes.

So which is the best way that we can store the document details(Like DocumentID) in email job while looping on to the document collection? We are writing the job in .net using c#.

Comment: a few clarifying questions; 1) when you say you have written a job, what is this job? are these "jobs" Functions? 

you should be able to access any of the document properties, including its "id" property.

Comment: @RyanCrawCour The job is nothing but console application which we add it in task scheduler. DocumentID is fine, but how can I store the DocumentID in memory, variable etc to understand it is already processed.

Comment: Are you asking how to communicate problem ids between different "job" processes? Is DocumentDB relevant at all to what you are trying to ask?

Comment: In new background email job only. Lets say I retrieved some Documents in job and then email is sent to problem IDs. After that background job runs again (interval set for 5 mins) and query the documents again and loop through the documents, then how can I sure for specific ID the email is already been sent. Because after each interval job will start its process from initial stage.

Comment: Well, you obviously need a persistent (out of process) storage for the fact if notification is sent or not. You could use anything (DB, local file, original docDB document, separate docDB document, etc) - it really depends on what you have and which properties you need. Please rethink/update your question to be more specific as it currently cannot be answered, just discussed. And this is not what SO is for.